# Need equivalent .htaccess rule in apache just like nginx so I can get everything in URL

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, php, .htaccess, rewrite

I have a VPS where I am using `nginx` and uses following to do URL rewriting.

```
location / {
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

Then I simply go to `index.php` and use the following code to get anything I want in URL and do the required thing.

```
$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

if(str_contains($request, "/login"))
        echo "show login page";
else if(str_contains($request, "/signup"))
        echo "show signup page";
else if(str_contains($request, "/signup/something/2"))
        echo "show something page";
else if($request == "/")
        echo "show home page";
else
        echo "redirect";
```

But the local machine where I am developing has `WAMP` which comes with `Apache`. What will be similar rule in `.htaccess` so I can get everything that is present in URL?

Answer (score 1):

I found it

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Minor point, but the `RewriteBase` directive is redundant here. You can also remove the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ (ie. change `/index.php` to `index.php`). For completeness, you also need `DirectoryIndex index.php` in order to route requests for the document root itself (if it's working without then that's because this is already defined in the server config - but it's not by default). If you are not using mod_rewrite for anything else you could simply use `FallbackResource /index.php` instead.

Comment: Thanks I have implemented these point.